# How can I cancel a stuck connection attempt with Palo GlobalProtect VPN on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I use Palo GlobalProtect VPN on Windows 10. Sometimes, it gets stuck while trying to connect to the VPN server:

[image]

How to cancel the connection attempt?

Comment: Have you tried `cmd.exe` `ipconfig /release`?

Comment: @Arctiic thanks, good point I haven't tried, I'll try next time it gets stuck!

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could find so far is to kill the `GlobalProtect client` process:

[image]